# XCode getting slow after choosing button title "Attributed" using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Don't know this is happening only with me or others are experiencing the same. Whenever I select any Button title from `plain to Attributed in Attributes inspector` on any ViewController, the Xcode getting too slow and hanging till that particular button is selected. Xcode works fine when I select any other control in ViewController. Anyone knows, why its happening and how to overcome from this problem? I am using Xcode7.2

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in `Xcode` that has not been resolved yet. It's always a pain for me to work with Attributed strings within `Interface Builder`. I advise you to copy/paste your string in order to reduce time in this tab.

Please fill a [bug report here](https://bugreport.apple.com), the more people will report, the faster the bug will be solve.